# Core Data Relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, one-to-many

I have the following files:

```
ProductViewController.h
ProductViewController.m
ComponentsViewController.h
ComponentsViewController.m
```

Inside `ProductViewController.m` I have my button where I save the product's info to my **sqlite** database by using core data. Inside `ComponentsViewController.m` I have my button to save the Components' info to my **sqlite**.
I have a **one-to-many** (product-to-components) relationship created in my datamodel. My problem is when I save my components info instead of assigning the components to my already created product the info gets saved to an "empty" product that gets created when I press the save components button. below my code:

```
ProductViewController.m

- (IBAction)saveProductButton:(id)sender {




    // Add product info to Data base

Product *newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    newProduct.prdname = self.name.text;
newProduct.prdtdesc = self.prdtdesc.text;
newProduct.prdtid = self.prdtid.text;

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    //  4
    self.name.text = @"";
    self.prdtid.text = @"";
    self.prdtdesc.text = @"";

    //  5
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}


ComponentsViewController.m

- (IBAction)addComponent:(id)sender {



Product *newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

 Components * newComponent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Components"
 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
 newComponent.prdtcompname = self.prdtcompname.text;
newComponent.prdtcompid = self.prdtcompid.text;
newComponent.prdtcompdesc = self.prdtcompdesc.text;
newComponent.prdtcompqt = self.prdtcompQT.text;

newProduct.tocomponents = [NSSet setWithObjects:newComponent, nil];


 NSError *error;
 if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
 NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }
 //  4

 self.prdtcompQT.text = @"";
 self.prdtcompname.text = @"";
 self.prdtcompid.text = @"";
 self.prdtcompdesc.text = @"";
 //  5
 [self.view endEditing:YES];

}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new product then in `addComponents:` if you want to add to an existing product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont Create a new product while creating a component. While creating a component, just fetch a product with the relative ID and store the product reference in component.

Here is my sample code:

I have created a same kind of one to many relationship (Item -> Item_Details)

Step 1: First i do insertion in item entity.

Step 2 : while Insertion of item_Details i just fetch item.info from the Item entity using the relative Id.

Once you create a NSManagedObjectSubClass (with relationship) it will automatically create the reference instance as u mentioned.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Item;

@interface Item_Detail : NSManagedObject


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * item_Id;      // Item_Id is a common id in both item and Item_details should act as a relation.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * item_Size;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * last_Modified;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * price;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Item *itemInfo;  // RelationShip reference

@end
```

**// Fetching the Item info with relationship ID:**

```
 +(Item *)getSourceItemDetail:(NSNumber *)itemId
    {
        NSEntityDescription *itemEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:[ASDataManager managedObjectContext]];
        NSFetchRequest *itemFetchRqt= [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        [itemFetchRqt setEntity:itemEntity];

        NSPredicate *itempredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item_Id = %@",itemId];
        [itemFetchRqt setPredicate:itempredicate];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *resultArray = [[ASDataManager managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:itemFetchRqt error:&error];

        if([resultArray count] == 1)
        {
            Item *item = (Item *)[resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
            return item;
        }
        return nil;
    }


//Item_Detail _Insertion
+(void)insertNewItemDetailRecordInItemDetailTable:(NSDictionary *)itemDetailDic
{

    Item_Detail *item_Dtls = (Item_Detail *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item_Detail" inManagedObjectContext:[ASDataManager managedObjectContext]];


    item_Dtls.item_Id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[itemDetailDic valueForKey:@"Item_ID"] intValue]];
    item_Dtls.item_Size = [ASGlobalInfoHelper getValueIfNotNullFrom:[itemDetailDic objectForKey:@"Item_Size"] valueType:ValueTypeString];

    item_Dtls.itemInfo = [self getSourceItemDetail:[NSNumber numberWithInt:@"90"]];
    //Getting Relationship data
    if(![[ASDataManager managedObjectContext] save:nil])
        NSLog(@"Error in Save");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ComponentsViewController.m`, you are creating an empty product here in this line:

```
Product *newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

If you want to have a relationship with newly created `Components` object with the previously created `Product` object, you either have to fetch the Product from Core Data using FetchRequest or pass the `Product` from `ProductViewController` to `ComponentsViewController`.

Comment: how can i pass the product from productviewcontroller to componentsviewcontroller? that is what i was trying to do but i just didn't know how.

Comment: How are you allocating/initiating ComponentsViewController object? Is there any relation between ProductViewController and ComponentsViewController ?

Comment: i created a fetch request on my AppDelegate which i use to populate a tableview with all the names of the products, once i click any product i get to the componentsviewcontroller's view to type the components info.

Comment: When you click on Tableview row, you must be using Tableview delegate, didSelectRowAtIndexPath and initiating and presenting ComponentsViewController. Create a propertt of type Product in ComponentsViewController and use it to pass the selectedProduct after initiating and before presenting ComponenrsViewController